# Node json-2-csv - How to select a header?

Tags: javascript

I'm using json-2-csv in node to replace a value on row 1.
I try to access Header "B" and replace the value "2" with "7" using this code:

```
    var C = "B"
    csvfile[itr].C = "7"
```

This is my csv file:

```
A, B, C

1, 2, 3
```

This is the output:

```
A, B, C

1, 2, 7
```

This is the preferred output:

```
A, B, C

1, 7, 3
```

Comment: have you tried  `csvfile[itr]["B"] = "7"` instead of `csvfile[itr].C = "7"`?

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning header column name to variable use it directly to assign new value, like,

```
csvfile[itr]["B"] = "7"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing `.X` with `[X]`. `.X` is the same as `['X']` (accessing property `X`) but what you need is `[X]` which accesses the property whose name is read from *variable* `X`.

So what you need is either `csvfile[itr][C]` or, if you want to get rid of the separate `C` variable entirely, `csvfile[itr].B` (which is the same as `csvfile[itr]['B']`).